# ARMv7 NEON: Unpack 32 bit mask to 64 bit mask

Tags: c++, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I have a 32 NEON bit mask that I need to unpack to 64 bits like so:

```c
uint32x4_t mask = { 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 0 };
uint64x2_t mask_lo = { 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF };
uint64x2_t mask_hi = { 0, 0 };
```

What I came up with so far is this:

```c
uint64x2_t mask_lo = vmovl_u32(vget_low_u32(mask));    // { 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, 0x00000000FFFFFFFF }
uint64x2_t mask_hi = vmovl_u32(vget_high_u32(mask));   // { 0, 0 }
```

The problem is, that it is missing the first two bytes of ones. I think it could be solved with `vtstq_u64`, but I am working with ARMv7, so it is sadly not avaiable for me.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** My bit mask elements are either all ones or all zeros!

**EDIT 2:** I just used `vmovl_s32` instead of `vmovl_u32`:

```c
mask_lo = vmovl_s32(vget_low_s32(vreinterpretq_s32_u32(mask)));
mask_hi = vmovl_s32(vget_high_s32(vreinterpretq_s32_u32(mask)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s unclear why do you want `0xFFFFFFFF` to unpack into `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

If you want sign extend, use reinterpret intrinsics, and `vmovl_s32` for the unpacking. This will unpack `0x80000000` into `0xFFFFFFFF80000000`

If instead you want to duplicate the `uint32_t` lanes, use `vzipq_u32` intrinsic with your source vector in both arguments. This will unpack `0x80000000` into `0x8000000080000000`

Comment: My bitmask elements are either all ones or all zeros, so both methods do the same for me. `vmovl_s32` is probably the faster one, so i will go with that. Thanks!